# How to solve time datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have take time (datatype) in mysql. In this column I want to use as a minutes. How to solve

when I use as a minutes(etr) then only take minutes value. I want to take minutes and hours both in one function

```
etr
01:00:00
00:30:00
00:15:00
```

I want to use minutes(etr) because this column subtract from another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is probably `time_to_sec()`:

```
select floor(time_to_sec(etr) / 60) as minutes
```

To be honest, it is not much more complicated to do:

```
select hour(etr) * 60 + minute(etr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hour() and minute() function

```
select hour(etr)*60 + minute(etr) from your_table
```